# Using higher capacity rechargeable batteries in device

Tags: battery-charging

Is there anything inadvisable about replacing a device's original NiMH batteries with others of much higher capacity? (For example, a cordless phone comes with 500 mAh cells, and I'd like to exchange them with 1500 mAh cells.) I'm thinking that the charging algorithm may be designed specifically for lower capacities, and will never fully charge the higher capacity cells, so the whole exchange might be an exercise in futility (or might even degrade the cell).

Answer (score 3):

I guess only manufacturer of this phone could give you 100% right answer, but I'm pretty sure it's perfectly fine to use 1500mAh cells instead of 500mAh. All common charging algorithms (trickle, delta-V, Temperature) are capacity-independent. And I don't think someone would implement timer-based charger in the phone.

Comment: actually, I did suspect that the phone uses a timer algorithm, since it displays "recharge for 7 hours" whenever batteries are inserted, regardless of their capacity or remaining charge.

Comment: The displayed advice to recharge for seven hours does not prove the phone uses a timer algorithm for charging.  It sounds more like an attempt to set customer expectations, and to warn that the phone should not be relied upon until theoretically charged.  You should interpret that advice now as "recharge for 21 hours".